# Recover Deleted File

Tags: data-recovery

I inadvertently deleted a directory containing several source code files.  I want them back.  I'm on a Linux Ubuntu machine.  The filesystem is NTSF.

I tried using TestDisk, but there are millions of deleted files in this partition.  TestDisk presents a curses interface which allows you to page through the deleted files.  But I can't search for the file I want.  I gave up after 15 minutes.  Is there another tool that allows me to undelete files without having to page through millions of file names?

I also looked at ddrescue, but that requires you to save the enture partition.  In my case that's 2 TB.  I don't have another 2TB of free space.

Answer (score -1):

ntfsundelete did the trick

ntfsundelete did the trick